# Projection in findAndModify query in nodejs mongodb driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I was unable to project only required fields from findAndModify query, it is returning whole document.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


db.collection("conf").findAndModify(
    searchDoc,
    sortDoc,
    {$set: updateDoc},
    {new: true},
    {"required_field": 1},
    function (error, obj) {
        console.log(obj["value"]);
        db.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

refs. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#find-and-modify

refs. https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/V2.1.3/lib/collection.js#L2319

```
collection.findAndModify(criteria[, sort[, update[, options]]], callback)
```

`optons` is key-value pair. it need field name. try following.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

db.collection("conf").findAndModify(
    searchDoc,          // criteria
    sortDoc,            // sort
    {$set: updateDoc},  // update
    {                   // options
        new: true,
        fields: {"required_field": 1}
    },
    function (error, obj) {
        console.log(obj["value"]);
        db.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using function `findAndModify` of mongodb nodejs driver. That `options` object is not for projection but for the behavior of the function

> Options object can be used for the following options:
>
> remove - if set to true (default is false), removes the record from the collection. Callback function still gets the object but it doesn’t exist in the collection any more.
>
> new - if set to true, callback function returns the modified record. Default is false (original record is returned)
>
> upsert - if set to true and no record matched to the query, replacement object is inserted as a new record

Even through the function `findAndModify` share the same name with a function of mongo shell, it may behave differently.You should check the doc here (https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#find-and-modify)

Comment: Yes, I know   "{new: true}" is the options object. But I just tried by adding my projection object after options object '{"required_field": 1}'. but it's not mentioned in docs. whatever the way I need to project only required_field.

Comment: @somallg You are right! But there is undocumented option `fields` in the code  ( https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/V2.1.3/lib/collection.js#L2319 ).